# How to build a jquery price calculator with the price decreasing based on quantities?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to allow potentials buyers to calculate price based on the number of items they want to buy.

The unit price of my products decreases depending on the quantity.

For example from 1 to 500 units the product costs 20$
From 500 to 1000 the price is 17$
From 1000 to 5000 the price is 13$ and so on ..

I've found scripts that calculate prices but they do that in a 'linear' way.
[Like this one for example](http://www.designsbymitch.com/envato/webEstimator/index.html)
[Or This one](http://www.speakingofcode.com/demos/developer/price_estimator/index.htm)

Is it possible to adapt these scripts to calculate the price with ‘breakpoints’ in the sliders ?
From 0 to 500 the total price will be = *20$ x number of items*
from 500 to 1000 the total price will be = *17$ x number of items* etc…

Thanks a lot

ps : as you can guess, i have basic programming skills

Comment: usually people post what they have tried. That help them to get faster answer

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what jQuery is. The scripting language that is run in browsers is known as JavaScript. JavaScript can do basic programmery things like math, and it can also do special tasks involving manipulating web documents, through an object model known as the DOM. Sometimes, though, you have to type a lot of JavaScript to manipulate the DOM, and you want to store all that code as functions and objects so you can reuse it and work faster. jQuery is an example of a library that provides functions to help you work with the DOM.

Comment: To do basic math, you don't need any jQuery. Simply think about your logic as a function, with a set of inputs and outputs, and write it as a JavaScript function.

Comment: @A.Wolff You are right, but since i didn't write any code, i posted links to scripts that do most of what i need and tried to explain the customization i need.

=> Asad : Thank you for your comment. I don't confuse JavaScript & jQuery. I specifically asked for _jQuery price calculator_ because i wanted to use the scripts i pointed at as a base and customize them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
// quantity segment, price
var priceRanges = [500,20,
                   1000,17,
                   5000,13];

//the function returns the unit price for a given quantity or -1 if out of range.
function getPrice(quantity){
   for (var i = priceRanges.length - 2 ; i >= 0 ; i-=2){
      if (quantity < priceRanges[i]) return priceRanges[i+1];
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a data structure that's something like this:

```
products = {
    7: {
        id: 7,
        title: "My Product",
        // note that the prices are in increasing order of minimum threshold
        // for quantity (i.e. 0 for 0-500, THEN 500 for 500-1000 THEN
        // 1000 for 1000-5000, etc., in that order)
        price: {
            0: 20,
            500: 17,
            1000: 13
        }
    },
    10: {
        id: 10,
        title: "My Other Product",
        price: {
            0: 50,
            500: 45,
            1000: 40
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Next, to calculate the price for product X (i.e. id = X) and quantity Q:

```
var correctPrice = -1;
for (var threshold in products[X].price) {
    if (Q >= threshold)
        correctPrice = products[X].price[threshold];
}

if (correctPrice > -1)
    // use correctPrice here
```

Using this, you can have an arbitrary number of products with arbitrary quantity thresholds and prices, and calculate using the correct price programmatically.

Comment: Thank you Hamza, since i'm still learning the basics of both Javascript and the jQuery library, you answer was helpful & insightful